# tensorflow 1.3.0 AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'function'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 1.3.0 (i'm using a code of some paper where they say the depencies is tf 1.3.0), and when I ran the the code I get:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sonnet/src/base.py in <module>()
     35 
     36 T = TypeVar("T")
---> 37 TFFunctionType = type(tf.function(lambda: None, autograph=False))  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
     38 APPLY_NAME_SCOPE = "__snt_with_name_scope"
     39 ALLOW_EMPTY_RESULT = "__snt_allow_empty_result"

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'function'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use google colab If it works there, try the following:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install --upgrade -r tensorflow_federated/requirements.txt
```